# How to define datasource for multiple connection (development and production) Prisma

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, prisma

I have a prisma configuration:
datasource db {
provider = "postgresql"
url      = "postgresql://johndoe:mypassword@localhost:5432/mydb?schema=public&sslmode=require&sslcert=../server-ca.pem&sslidentity=../client-identity.p12&sslpassword="
}
Will like to know how we can specify the development and test DB explicitly

Answer (score -1):

You can use [dotenv-cli] to specify the database URL's for *dev* and *test*.

[Here](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/tools-and-interfaces/prisma-schema#manage-env-files-manually) it's explained how you can switch the URL based on the env file that you have.